# best way to create API

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, asp.net-web-api

We are about to create an API so that our customers can connect to us, subscribe to a service and then consume that service. what is the best way to implement this? we work in C#, .NET. We want something like this:
we will provide a username and password to our customer to connect with our API. (how to implement this, using database?)?
after successful connection , customer will subscribe to our service. (how to check that customer is already connected? )
after subscription customer can calls API methods.

kindly tell me the best way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple solution is to supply a *Login* method, your customers must call this one with username and password before consume the service, you can issue a token to the client once username/password validated, usually stored in a database; then the client can call your API method with the token attached for each request so you can check whether the client has called *Login* method or not; the token will be destroyed after the client finished using service by either providing a *Logout* method or setting up a expire time for each token.

This is for your consideration. About "best" way, I think there's no such one way best for all situation. You will find the best way for you.

Comment: i also want my service to communicate with mobiles phones. like many of my customers will be using that service from iphon/android. so what is the right technology for it?

Comment: anything http based should work fine from mobile devices

Comment: @ExploringTech I think http works well for both pc client and mobile client.

Comment: what about simple .net webservices?  or wcf? or any other technology you want me to consider?

Comment: simple .net web service is fine. I prefer a restful style service avoid handling soap messages of web services and json for data wrap, because soap is not that necessary for most of cases and a simple http transfer is more common for mobile platforms.

Comment: I started another thread , can you have a look onto it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645572/client-server-24-7-listner/8645715#8645715

Answer (score 1):

Have you ever look [servicestack](http://servicestack.net/) ? It's awesome ,totally DTO based and very easy to create API for .net

Please look out my [blog post](http://www.arunrana.net/2011/11/introduction-of-servicestack.html) about that

Check this thread for **authentication** options in ServiceStack.

https://groups.google.com/d/topic/servicestack/U3XH9h7T4K0/discussion

Look at example [here](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/RequestFiltersTests.cs)

Comment: will it provide communication between my service and mobile devices ?

Comment: Yes definitely see this link http://www.servicestack.net/mythz_blog/?p=417

Answer (score 0):

This might inspire you or prove useful.

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b1d767d9-d6bf-41ee-89a8-313d338e63b6

There are also some links in there that talk about using API keys so you can control who's using your api why that's essential.