# Client Server 24/7 Listner

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

We want to implement a client server application. here is the scenario. 
Server listens for client 24/7. 
Server accept request for client and save it in DB for further process.
Once processing is done (it may take few hours), Server will response back to client.

in short , client and server listens for each other 24/7.

I want to implement it in C# but i also want that it should be accessibly from all platforms.
Also is it possible in WCF?

Comment: Your question describes a pretty basic WCF service application. "Listening 24/7" is the default behavior.

Comment: guys how can i accept an answer which does not solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Yuck, this is a basic WCF scenario.  There a few articles, videos and tutorials to get you started here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/dd939784

Comment: WCF can listen from client 24/7 , but how i can send back responses to client using WCF? like client send me request "A" at time T1, I hold the request "A" and after Time T100 i want to send back the response , how can i do this in WCF?

Comment: If you are looking for more specifics to your scenario about listening for the event once your work has completed, here is an MSDN article that covers publishing and subscribing to events using WCF. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163537.aspx

Comment: where is the link? okay i found it.

Comment: I got this link, i will study it and try to implement it. then i will come back to you. its looking good. thanks